# UIScrollView isn't working (can't scroll)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I'm adding a UIScrollView to the reusable view I'm making and then adding that reusable view to a UIViewController.

In my reusable view I'm adding UIViews to the UIScrollView :

```
 int yLocation = 20;
    for (int i= 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
        UIView *tempView = [[offerCell alloc]initWithDelegate:self];
        tempView.frame = CGRectMake(5, yLocation, 290.0F, 70.0F);

        yLocation += 90;

        [self.scrollView addSubview:tempView];
        UILabel *tempLabel = [tempView viewWithTag:1000];
        tempLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Label Number %d" , i];
        [tempLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(1000, 1000)];
    } 
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, yLocation);
```

Then I'm adding the UIView to my UIViewController

```
UIView *tempView = [[BuyTokensView alloc] initWithDelegate:self andViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:tempView];
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(10, 0);
tempView.center = point;
```

The view is shown correctly but I can't scroll the UIScrollView. My UIScrollView height is smaller than the Height I'm assigning in ContentSize, so why can't I scroll?

Here is a picture of the UIViewController:
[image: image 1]

Comment: log scrollview height. Check whether you add scrollview as subview.

Comment: I add the scrollview as a subview I wrote that, and the height is fine.

Comment: i think you should add tempview over scrollview [self.scrollView addSubView:tempView]

Comment: @AravindBG what do you mean? I add tempView to scrollView..  `[self.scrollView addSubview:tempView]`;

Comment: i am telling about the second code snippet.

Comment: @AravindBG I can't do that. the ScrollView is Part of the reusable UIView I'm creating. I add the ScrollView to the xib file.

Comment: Log the scroll view's contentSize in viewDidAppear

Comment: @yurish `scrollView Height: 331.000000, scrollView ContentHeight: 470.000000`

Comment: Are these values taken in viewDidAppear? When do you add the reusable view to the window hierarchy? in viewDidLoad?

Comment: @yurish I'm adding the reusable view in viewDidLoad and the values is logged in viewDidAppear

Comment: Can you see the scroll view itself on the screen? For example, what happens if you assign some contrast background to the scrollview?

Comment: @yurish see the pic i added to the question.

Comment: Hard to tell. Other than something is wrong with touch events handling I have no idea. Root view where you plug the reusable view is too small, touch events handling is turned off etc.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard with autolayout somewhere? That can cause a scrollview to not scroll unless set up properly.

Comment: @JakobW yeah I'm using storyboard with autolayout, I just dragged a UIScrollView to my xib where i designed the reusable View, what could I do wrong?

Comment: @BlueGene Posted an answer, hope it can help you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can try to disable autolayout or use the strategies in this technical note:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013309

Comment: I tried the mixed approach which was just setting my `scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;` but it didn't help. I also tried turning off AutoLayout and it didn't help so I don't think the problem is AutoLayout related.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Xcode 6/iOS 8+ now with auto-layout turned on, and I had the same problem in the first place, removing auto-layout doesn't work at all, so in order to make scroll view scrollable vertically, I made sure the following:

1. The scroll view content size height MUST be bigger than the screen height, this almost goes without saying...
2. The top/bottom/left/right constraint of the scroll view HAS TO BE pinned, I did this using storyboard so no code showing up here

If you want to make the scroll view scrollable horizontally, then make sure its content size width is bigger than the screen width, the other rule applies the same.

This worked for me, hope it can help someone.